# Number of elements of group with specific order

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the group $(G,\cdot)$ where $$G=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1&a\\0&b\end{matrix}\right):a,b\in\mathbb{R}, b\neq0\right\}.$$ How many members of $G$ have order 2?

**My Attemt**

A member $M$ of $G$ will have order two iff $M^2=I$. I.e. $$\left(\begin{matrix}1&a\\0&b\end{matrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{matrix}1&a+ab\\0&b^2\end{matrix}\right)=I.$$This is true for $b=1$ and $a=0$ in which case $M=I$ or in the case $b=-1$ and $a$ is any real. Hence, there is an infinite number of elements with order 2 in $G$.

Can somebody please verify that this is true?

Comment: Your answer is excellent, assuming that you mean "$a,b\in \mathbb{R}$" rather than "$ab\in \mathbb{R}$", as written.  Come to think of it, it's right as written also.

Comment: Verified. It is true.

Comment: It is correct...

Comment: @vadim123 Yes, thanks, this is what I mean. I corrected it in case anybody wants to have a look at this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very well argued. You are entirely correct.

On the light side: You can stamp your answer *Verified @MSE*.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what did you [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/573371/revisions)? I see only 109 characters, but you *added 160 characters in body*...